# AJAX Call to 3 Web services

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a 3 ajax calls into one but I only get one at the moment. This is what I am doing:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/Ws.aspx/One",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result1) {
        $('#hpl_one').html(result1.d);
    }
}),


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/Ws.aspx/Two",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result2) {
        $('#hpl_two').html(result2.d);
    }
}),


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/Ws.aspx/Three",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result3) {
        $('#hpl_three').html(result3.d);
    }
}),
```

Now I want to be able to call these three methods but I get only one at the moment:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/Ws.aspx/One",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result1) {
                $('#hpl_one').html(result1.d);
            }
        });
        // end  calling ajax to count alert
    }, 3000);
});
```

In the HTML I have:

```
<a id="hpl_one" runat="server">---</a>
<a id="hpl_two" runat="server">---</a>
<a id="hpl_three" runat="server">---</a>
```

I can get **hpl_one** but I do not know the syntax to call **hpl_two** and **hpl_three** in the success clause, thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you trying to make a "different" Ajax call every three seconds (inside the `setInterval` callback) and don't know how to parametrize the call? Or do you want to execute each of those Ajax calls every three seconds? The first snippet showing all the call looks good to me, so I don't understand where you are having troubles with.

Comment: i did not get your question properly ? are you trying to post within success of previous ajax request ?

Comment: You cannot access 3 URLs at once by typing 3 URLs into your browser address bar either. Ajax calls are asynchronous so that's almost close to parallel even if your calls are fired one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickest I can think of .. make a function containng all three calls and call that function

```
function makeAjax()
{
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/Ws.aspx/One",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result1) {
        $('**#hpl_one**').html(result1.d);
    }
}),


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/Ws.aspx/Two",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result2) {
        $('**#hpl_two**').html(result2.d);
    }
}),


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/Ws.aspx/Three",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result3) {
        $('**#hpl_three**').html(result3.d);
    }
})
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    var refreshId = setInterval(makeAjax, 3000);
});
```

Comment: `setInterval('makeAjax', 3000);` should be `setInterval(makeAjax, 3000);`. Otherwise nothing would happen.

Comment: @FelixKling, sorry for not been clear with my question. I am trying to execute each of these ajax calls every 3 seconds. Let's Code solution does indeed what I need. Thank you so much Let's Code for the great answer and thanks Felix Kling for helping out. Its works perfectly well now!